# Rate of decay of Fourier coefficients on heat equation solution

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

Let $u(x,t) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j^0 e^{-j^2t}\sin(jx)$ be the solution for the heat equation, where $u_j^0 = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int_0^\pi u^0(x)\sin(jx)\;dx$ are the Fourier coefficients of the initial data $u^0$.

Suppose that $u_j^0 = C/j$.
Prove that $\left\lVert\frac{d}{dt}u(\cdot,t)\right\rVert\leq \frac{C}{t^{3/4}}$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

This is a problem from "[Numerical Solution of Partial Differential Equations by the Finite Element Method](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Numerical_Solution_of_Partial_Differenti.html?id=0IFCAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)", by Claes Johnson. I am having trouble to relate the decay rate of the Fourier coefficient with the boundness on the time derivative.

The book also uses as an example that $\left\lVert \frac{d}{dt}u(\cdot,t)\right\rVert\leq \frac{C}{t^{1/4}}$ when $u_j^0 = C/j^2$ and $t \rightarrow 0$.

While I can see that $\left\lVert\frac{d}{dt}u(\cdot,t)\right\rVert\leq \frac{C}{t}$ is true because:

$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j^0 (-j^2)\frac{t}{t} e^{-j^2t}\sin(jx) \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty u_j^0 \frac{C}{t}\sin(jx)$$

I don't see how I can use that $u_j^0 = C/j$ to change the value from $1$ to $\frac{3}{4}$.